# USB-C breakout board, using V and G with a NiMH charger am I doing this wrong?

Tags: soldering, usb-c, nimh, breakout

I’m pretty new to electronics so trying to find my way around.

I’ve purchased this breakout USB-C:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Chenyang-24pin-Female-Socket-Connector/dp/B00VJ944V2

And this NiMH battery charger:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Battery-Dedicated-Charging-2S-Without-Terminal/dp/B087NVJBCX

I’m connecting using 30-gauge wire. My understanding is that I need to solder the V and G on the breakout to the GND and VIN on the NiMH charger. It doesn’t really work or do anything after soldering (besides flash red once very dim) but only if I plug the charger in. If I grab my cell battery pack and connect the + and - to the NiMH board it also just flashes red once. All signs are pointing to me not understanding this correctly so any pointers would really help.

Essentially I am wanting to supply some kind of power to the board to then connect the other end of the NiMH board to a battery to charge a small device. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: If I am understanding what you are saying it should work however 30AWG wire is very light for this type of application, about 100 ohms per 1K feet.. I am assuming V is connected to Vin and G is connected to Gnd, the opposite of how you stated it.

Comment: Thanks @Gil yes that’s correct V to VIN and G to GND. This is the video I am following and the guy suggested 30AWG in the comments, he appears to be using the same wire and NiMH board as I have purchased - I have tested both boards to make sure they’re not duff and both flash red once: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glz8QctjjtY

Comment: https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm "Maximum amps for
power transmission"  AWG30: 0.142A. If you only ever expect this to draw ~100mA then those wires can be used. If you expect to use this for USB charger type of applications, those wires will burn up instantly.

Comment: Also that youtube video is a perfect example of how not to do soldering. Fix everything in place so that it is steady before doing anything. And solder is not silver-colored hot glue, it needs to wet across both surfaces, not just get melted into a blob.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin - what wire size would you suggest for me to succeed in my mission? :-)

Comment: What's your charger's current rating? Charge currents can be several Ampere.

Comment: @Lupin Charger details here, thank you! https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Charger-Adapter-Compatible-Wireless/dp/B08ZCPTP5X

Comment: @Lundin typo for tagging you previous comment above :-)

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I could help.